# How to highlight the main navigation bar and the side navigation bar simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jquery-events

The below page has both side as well as a main navigation bar. I am currently using the current url to highlight the corresponding navigation bar. Please find below the code I am using:

```js
highlightSection = function() {
  var url = location.href.toLowerCase();
  $("#navbar li a").each(function() {
    if (url == this.href.toLowerCase()) {
      $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    }
  });

  $(".nav-sidebar li a").each(function() {
    if (url == this.href.toLowerCase()) {
      var nav;

      if ( url.indexOf('/brand') !== -1 ) {
        nav = App.contextPath + "/brand/home";
      } else if ( url.indexOf('/Options') !== -1 ) {
        nav = App.contextPath + "/Options";
      } else if ( url.indexOf('/ratings') !== -1 ) {
        nav = App.contextPath + "/ratings/home";
      } else {
        nav = App.contextPath + "/admin/home";
      }

      $(this).parent().addClass("active");
      $('#navbar li:has(a[href="' + nav + '"])').addClass("active");
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Tool</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navbar">
        <li><a href="/brand/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Options">Options</a></li>
        <li><a href="/ratings/home">Ratings</a></li>          
        <li><a href="/admin/home">Admin</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Add </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">View/Modify</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Delete</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here , when the user clicks on the main navigation bar, the corresponding `li` is highlighted based on the href.
When the user clicks on the side navigation bar the same logic is used to highlight the side navigation bar but here to keep the main navigation bar highlighted at the same time I am checking if the url contains a certain text.

Here, under each main navigation bar there is a set of corresponding side navigation bars.
The js `highlightSection` is called on page load.

For example, if the user selects **Home** on the main navbar the entire page loads and the Home tab is highlighted based on the url.
Now , when the user selects **Delete** on the sidebar the entire page loads and the Delete sidebar is highlighted based on the url. Here, in order to keep Home highlighted when Delete is selected I am checking if the url contains a certain text. So, in this example is there any better way of keeping the Home tab highlighted in the main navbar when Delete is selected on the sidebar navigation?

Could you suggest a better way of highlighting the main navigation bar simultaneously when the user clicks on the side navigation bar without checking the current url?

Comment: To get things straight.. So you basically want to highlight the current page nav listitem? with shorter code

Comment: Testing this here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3pqx017f/ it does not make a lot of sense. It's not clear what you want highlighted when.

Comment: For example when the user clicks on Home button the Home tab needs to be highlighted. But next when the user clicks on the side bar Delete both Home as well as Delete need to be Highlighted

Comment: *"a better way of highlighting the main navigation bar "* - that doesn't make sense. How come the main navigation bar is not already highlighted? How is the method `highlightSection` called?

Comment: The highlightSection is called by default whenever the page loads. Here, when the user clicks on the main navbar or sidebar the entire page is loaded

Comment: save status to cookie or localstorage

Comment: In this case if the user  hits the sidebar url directly then this logic wont work

Comment: @user2077648.. instead of adding 'active' class to anchor tag from JS. Just add a new css style like a:active{background-color:red}. This will do the job and you dont need to worry about adding and removing the css class all the time.

Comment: Here, the tab needs to be highlighted based on what the user selects so this has to be changed according to which tab is currently selected by the user.

Comment: Is it possible for you to make small changes in the structure?

Comment: Why not add the selected sidebar action to the url as a parameter? e.g. `http://mywebsite.com/brand/home?action=delete` and then set the selected sidebar based on this extra parameter?

Answer (score 1):

well, on a quick look check the below code,

```
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Tool</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navbar">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ratings</a></li>          
            <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar" id="sidebar">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Add </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">View/Modify</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Delete</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$('#navbar a').click(function(){
$('#navbar li.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
})
$('#sidebar a').click(function(){
$('#sidebar li.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
})
</script>
<style>
.active{
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

As user click on the navigation bar, $('#navbar a').click() this fucntion will be called, and we will first clear all the active class containing within the `<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navbar">....</ul>` this element. and then adds the active class on the parent element of the clicked element get using this. same for the sidebar nav

Comment: Can you explain this in further detail so future visitors understand this answer better?

Comment: This answer will not work as the page is loaded each time the user selects a particular tab. Here, the active class need to be set when the page loads based on what the user has selected.

Comment: Well I thought that's for single page application

Comment: sorry @micheal for not explaining . Done with the Description

Answer (score 1):

I had commented with a jsfiddle that was getting there, but plnkr.co is a better option for this example.

My Working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/9YHEVfPqdqafBjiKbueS?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <script data-require="jquery@1.11.3" data-semver="1.11.3" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" data-semver="3.3.6" data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" />
    <script src="code.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> Tool</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul id="navbar" class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
              <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="options.html">Options</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="ratings.html">Ratings</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="admin.html">Admin</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#">Add </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">View/Modify</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Delete</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  var url = location.href.toLowerCase();
  var action = getURLParam("action");
  console.log("Current URL: ", url);
  console.log("Action: ", action);

  function getURLParam(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
      var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
      if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
        return sParameterName[1];
      }
    }
  }

  // Highlight Active link for current page
  $("#navbar li a").each(function(k, v) {
    var target = v.href.toLowerCase();
    console.log("Seeking withinin: ", target);
    if (url.indexOf(target) !== -1) {
      console.log(url.indexOf(target), " Active: ", this);
      $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    }
    if(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1 == url.length){
      console.log("No match, highlighting Home.");
      $("#navbar li a[href='index.html']").parent().addClass("active");
    }
  });
  // Populate Action links and highlight
  $(".nav-sidebar li a").each(function(k, v) {
    var targetPage = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    if(targetPage.indexOf("?")){
      targetPage = targetPage.substring(0, targetPage.indexOf("?"));
    }
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() == action) {
      console.log("Highlighting Action: ", $(this).text().toLowerCase());
      $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    }
    v.href = targetPage + "?action=" + $(this).text().toLowerCase();
  });
});
```

In this example, you would need to change the paths back to your own. When you click on Home, Option, Ratings, or Admin, that will be highlighted (it's parent gets class `active`) when the page loads. When you then click on Add, View/Modify, Delete it's parent gets highlighted (the class `active` gets added to it's parent) when the page loads. You can see this when you inspect each `li`.

Based on your description, that addresses the various scenarios you described.

Comment: I am looking for an approach where the active class is added to the main navbar without checking the current url.

Comment: Then what do you want check? You didn't specify.